# Compactly supported infinitely differentiable function constant on an interval

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I know a typical example of compactly supported infinitely differentiable function to be defined by $$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{\frac{1}{(\beta-x)(\alpha-x)}}, & \alpha<x<\beta \\ 0, &x\notin (\alpha,\beta) \end{cases}$$Can a compactly supported infinitely differentiable function be explicitly defined to be constant on a certain interval? I have not been able to get anything by using piecewise defined functions with exponentials. Thank you very much for any answer!

Comment: I don't have a full answer currently because I don't have a source but the answer is yes, given that the interval you want to be constant on is compactly contained in your domain.

Comment: @DanZimm Thank you so much! Knowing that it can be explicitly expressed is a good step toward finding an explicit expression.

Comment: @DanZimm I've quoted Kolmogorov-Fomin's example here at p. 211: http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol2/Mathematics/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2,%D0%A4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD,_%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B8_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA_%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0,1976.pdf

Comment: ah my apologies, missed a minus in my own work!

Comment: @DanZimm No problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider a smooth function $g$ with compact support (say $[-1, 1]$) and $h(x):=\int_{-\infty}^xg(t)\mathrm dt$. We have $h(x)=0$ if $x\lt -1$, $h(x)=\int_{-1}^1 g(t)\mathrm dt$ for $x \gt 1$. The function $h$ is smooth. Consider $f(x):=h(x)h(a-x)$ for a well choosen $a$ in order to get a function constant on $(1,2)$, say.

Comment: Thank you very much and have a happy 2015!

Answer (score 1):

Now that you have one nice $C^{\infty}_{0}$ function, you can make babies using mollification. For example, define $\rho(x)=0$ for $|x| \ge 1$, and define
$$
            \rho(x) = C \exp\left\{\frac{1}{x^{2}-1}\right\}, \;\;\; -1 < x < 1,
$$
where $C$ is chosen so that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\rho(x)dx = 1$. Define $\rho_{n}(x)=n\rho(nx)$. Use this to mollify the step function
$$
        \varphi_{n} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\rho_{n}(x-y)\chi_{[-1,1]}(y)\,dy.
$$
This is a $C^{\infty}_{0}$ function for all $n$ and, for large enough $n$, it is easily verified that $\varphi_{n}$ is identically $1$ in a neighborhood of $0$.

Comment: Thank you so much for all the interesting facts of mollifier theory I've learnt from you!

Comment: @DavideZena : You are welcome.